# Redirect from an IP address to IP/wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to get a Wordpress install to redirect to the /wordpress/ directory instead of having to type the IP address/wordpress/ to display the web site.  I used bitnami to install and when I type in the IP the initial bitnami page will display.  I just need for users to be able to type in the IP address so that the server will direct them to x.x.x.x/wordpress/ for Intranet purposes.  Please help.

Comment: Do you have access to the root of the server? You can put an HTML file that will make the redirection to the path you want.

Comment: Yes I have access to the root of the server.  This server is more or less of a test machine that I'm using to rebuild our Intranet.  I just need to know where to put the HTML file.  I'm guessing that's where the bitnami page is that's displaying now.  Do I just put an index.html there?  Can you tell me the syntax for the redirection?

Comment: I found the html file and it's in apache.  I just need to make a new index.html to redirect to the path that I need.  Now I just need the syntax for the html file.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml